# Getting a "Cannot provide direction" in maps when passing address in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, didselectrowatindexpath

I need some help when user clicks on the table view cell when there is a address to open maps and directions will happen.. Unfortunately, I get the error when user clicks on the address table view cell  which is "Cannot provide direction from and to of the same direction". So, here is my code below.

Here is my code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cellId = infoCellId
    if indexPath.section != 0 {
      cellId = interactiveCellId
    }

    let cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId)! as UITableViewCell
    var key = "Not Available"
    var value = "Not Available"

    if indexPath.section == 0  {
      if indexPath.row == 0 {
        key = "Name"
        if self.place.placeName.characters.count > 0 {
          value = self.place.placeName
        }
      } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        key = "Address"
        if let address = self.place.address {
          if address.characters.count > 0 {
            value = address

          }
        }

      } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        key = "Phone number"


        if let phoneNumber = self.place.phoneNumber {

          if phoneNumber.characters.count > 0 {
            value = phoneNumber
         }
        }

      } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        key = "Website"
        if let website = self.place.website {
          if website.characters.count > 0 {
            value = website
          }
        }
      }
    }


    else if indexPath.section == 2 {
      key = "Get Directions"
    } else {
      key = "Photos of \(self.place.placeName)"
    }

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
      cell.textLabel?.text = key
      cell.detailTextLabel?.text = value
    } else {
      cell.textLabel?.text = key



    }

    return cell
  }


 // ---- didSelectRowAt Happpening here ----- 

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

if indexPath.section == 0 {

  if indexPath.row == 1 {
    print("it works!")

    if let location = place.location {
      if let url = URL(string:"http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=\(location.coordinate.longitude),\(location.coordinate.latitude)") {
      UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
  }
  }

        if indexPath.row == 2 {



        guard let phoneNumber = self.place.phoneNumber,
          phoneNumber.count > 0,



        let url = URL(string: "tel:\(phoneNumber.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)!)")



          else { return }

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
          UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)


        }

      } else { return }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the same location for the start and destination of your navigation, so the error message is to be expected.

If you want to provide directions from the user's current location, you need only provide the destination.

Also, you have transposed the latitude and longitude values in the URL.

Finally, you are using string interpolation with an optional, so the url you are going to get is something like `http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=(optional)x,(optional)y`

You should unwrap `place.location` first.

```
if let coordinate = place.location?.coordinate {
    if let url = URL(string:"http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=\(coordinate.longitude),\(coordinate.latitude)") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah. But why the address not passing when I even applied your snippet.? I am getting `To Option`  now.

Comment: If you are using the iOS10 or later SDK then the method is `open(url, options:,completionHandler:)` - see my updated answer - you have the right call in your `tel:` code

Comment: that's what I implement it.. it is giving me `To Option` for my destination though.

Comment: What do you mean "To Option?"  The URL format I have is working for me - it opens the map with the directions dialog shown.

Comment: That looks correct; It is showing the routing options from your current location to the destination.  You might want a faster route or a slower route that avoids tolls.

Comment: check my current code. that is not the current route though

Comment: You have transposed the latitude and longitude values; longitude comes first

Comment: I fixed it.  but, it is still showing the same "To option" as my destination. :/

Comment: You need to confirm your data then.  The URL format in my answer is correct, if the destination is wrong then you are sending the wrong latitude and longitude.  What latitude and longitude values are you sending?

Comment: how can I fix it though?

Comment: I am sending from my object `Places` where It is populating the address and when user clicks on it - it shows destination in maps.

Comment: You are using string interpolation on an optional, which means your url isn't valid

Comment: No, unwrap `location` first.

Comment: it still wanting me to wrap an optional

Comment: What does it say is optional?

Comment: it is saying `Value of optional type 'CLLocation?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use to ! or ?`

Comment: should I make my ` var coordinate :CLLocationCoordinate2D?` as () ?

Comment: Did you change the interpolated string to refer to `location` not `place.location`?

Comment: should I initialize with `var location = CLLocation2D()?`

Comment: No,  `location` is provided by the `if let location = place.location`

Comment: check my updated question to check if I did implement it correctly?

Comment: It looks like `place.location.coordinate` is also an optional - see my edit

Comment: second `if-let` are you missing a `opening -closing curly braces`?

Comment: +1 for the help. But, it still shows `-202424 integer for my destination but it says Directions not available` .

Comment: -202424 is not a valid latitude or longitude; you need to look at your data